# colcon test returning return code 5 even though tests aren't failing

Tags: ros2, colcon, xml, unit-testing

When running python tests using colcon, the run_test.py return code is 5, leading to overall test failures. The test file contains 10 tests, none of them marked as `unstable` via `@pytest.mark.unstable`. If I mark one of the tests as `unstable` (doesn't matter which one), then the overall test result is a success with a return code of 0. Unsure what this return code means, as none of the result files show any issues with the tests themselves.

Context: test_example.py contains 10 tests, none of which are marked using `@pytest.mark.unstable`. I run the colcon tests two ways (both of which yield the same issue):

Method 1

```
export PYTEST_ADDOPT="-m 'unstable'"
/usr/bin/colcon test --parallel-workers 16 --ctest-args --output-on-failure --packages-select <PACKAGE> --return-code-on-test-failure
```

Method 2

```
/usr/bin/colcon test --parallel-workers 16 --ctest-args --output-on-failure --packages-select <PACKAGE> --pytest-args " -m 'unstable'"
```

Pytest (via colcon) clearly only runs tests marked unstable, which in this case don't exists, as no test is marked unstable, since the output shows that 10 tests were deselected.

Output of the result XML file:

```
  <<< failure message
    Running with ROS_DOMAIN_ID 1
    -- run_test.py: invoking following command in '/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/build/<PACKAGE>':
     - /<HOME>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/envs/<ENV>/bin/python3.10 -u -m pytest /<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/src/<PACKAGE>/tests/test_example.py -o cache_dir=/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/<PROJECT_DIR>/build/<PACKAGE/ament_cmake_pytest/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/src/<PACKAGE>/tests/test_example.py/.cache --junit-xml=/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/build/<PACKAGE>/test_results/<PACKAGE>//<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/src/<PACKAGE>/tests/test_example.py.xunit.xml --junit-prefix=<PACKAGE>
    ============================= test session starts ==============================
    platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
    cachedir: build/<PACKAGE>/ament_cmake_pytest/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/src/<PACKAGE>/tests/test_example.py/.cache
    rootdir: /<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>
    configfile: pyproject.toml
    plugins: ament-copyright-0.14.1, ament-pep257-0.14.1, ament-flake8-0.14.1, ament-xmllint-0.14.1, ament-lint-0.14.1, launch-testing-ros-0.24.0, launch-testing-2.0.2, cov-4.1.0, anyio-3.7.1, typeguard-2.13.3, colcon-core-0.12.1, dash-2.9.3, rerunfailures-12.0, retry-1.4.1, repeat-0.9.1
    collected 10 items / 10 deselected / 0 selected
    
    - generated xml file: /<HOME>/>PROJECT_DIR>/build/<PACKAGE>/test_results/<PACKAGE>/<HOME>/>PROJECT_DIR>/src/<PACKAGE>/tests/test_example.py.xunit.xml -
    ============================ 10 deselected in 0.53s ============================
    -- run_test.py: return code 5
    -- run_test.py: verify result file '/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/build/<PACKAGE>/test_results/<PACKAGE>/<HOME>/<PROJECT_DIR>/src/<PACKAGE>/tests/test_example.py.xunit.xml'
  >>>
```

The result file linked above shows the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><testsuites><testsuite name="pytest" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" tests="0" time="0.402" timestamp="2023-08-30T12:18:39.943209" hostname="user-ubuntu" /></testsuites>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.